# mount all harddisks in a folder after reboot like `ls /mnt/ | sudo mount`

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

I have a specific issue with mounting harddrives:

When using fstab to automount on boot, my system will crash on boot in some instances because the system fails to scan and fix a harddrive automatically. This is unsuitable, as I do not have physical access to the system in order to manage recovery mode and scan/fix the affected harddrive (for example after electricity outage). Additionally other important services will not be running in this case.
The issue seems to be caused by automatic mount/scan/repair of the harddrive fails. Likely due to not enough system memory for checking through 200 TB of storage.

I have tried plenty of things such as `nofail,errors=continue`, setting the harddrives into sequential scanning/fixing mode (pass `2`) and mounting the harddrives read-only. After more than 6 months of unsuccessful attempts with troubleshooting advice of the ubuntu forums and plenty of questions in askubuntu on how mount works, I decide to replicate my working manual process rather than using fstab to automount on boot.

For this reason, I set the options in fstab to `noauto`. This will cause the system to not mount my archive drives on startup. But also `sudo mount -a` won't do with that switch.
Mounting the harddrives manually after system boot with 'sudo mount /mnt/mydrive1' will work and the system will not crash on mounting failure.
That's why I thought `ls /mnt/ | sudo mount` might do but it does not.
How would I proceed with mounting all harddrives in `/mnt/` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script mount_harddisks.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -d -L /mnt/* | xargs -L1 -t sudo mount
```

create service mount_harddisks.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Harddrive mounting service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=no
ExecStart=bash /{path to script}/mount_harddisks.bash

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```